# How to pull & run docker image on remote server through jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have 2 aws ubuntu instance: 1st-server and 2nd-server.

Below is my jenkins pipeline script which create docker image and runs container on 1st-server and push the image to docker hub repo. That's working fine.

I want to pull image and deploy it on 2nd-server.

When I do ssh for 2nd server through below pipeline script but it logins to 1st-server, even if ssh credential ('my-ssh-key') are of 2nd-server. I'm confused how it logging to 1st-server and I checked with touch commands so the file is creating on 1st-server.

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    registry = "docker-user/docker-repo"
    registryCredential = 'docker-cred'
    dockerImage = ''
  }
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
      steps {
        git url: 'https://github.com/git-user/jenkins-flask-tutorial.git/'
      }
    }
    stage('Building image') {
      steps{
        script {
          sh "sudo docker build -t flask-app-one ."
          sh "sudo docker run -p 5000:5000 --name flask-app-one -d flask-app-one "
          sh "docker tag flask-app-one:latest docker-user/myrepo:flask-app-push-test"
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Push Image') {
      steps{
        script {
          docker.withRegistry( '', registryCredential ) {
          sh "docker push docker-user/docker-repo:flask-app-push-test"
          sshagent(['my-ssh-key']) {
            sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@2ndserver && cd /home/ubuntu/ && sudo touch test-file && docker pull docker-user/docker-repo:flask-app-push-test'
          }
         } 
        }
      }
    }
```

My question is, how to login to 2nd server and pull the docker image on 2nd server via through jenkins pipeline script? Help me out where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Note: you can restrict the `authorized_keys` [`command`](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/openssh#command="cmd") to run a i.e. `deploy.sh` script that exists on the remote server with the commands to deploy the images and use [`ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) to hide the connection details (e.g. `User`) for the host. Then it's just a `ssh 2ndserver` in your pipeline step.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with your `ssh` command, you're `&&` chaining the commands together (e.g. if `ssh` returns `0` then `cd ...` - you don't want `ssh` to exit) when what you want to do is execute the commands on the remote host (e.g. `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@2ndserver "cd /home/ubuntu/ && ..."`). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64120856/1423507) is correct.

Comment: You would want to specify the first server as the `agent` for the initial stages, and then the second server as the `agent` for the later stages. `agent any` is blocking you here.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of an alternative than a solution. You can execute the remote commands as part of ssh. This will execute the command on the server and disconnect.

```
ssh name@ip "ls -la /home/ubuntu/"
```